# Normal map when painting in blender

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, texture-painting

I am painting a model using the texture paint tool.  I am painting the diffuse of a moss texture onto a building I created.  I also have a normal map that goes with the moss texture.  Is there a way for me to recover the UV coordinates that are being generated when I paint my model.

There must be some mapping between what is appearing in my texture that I am painting and the texture attached to my brush.  How can I recover these coordinates so that I can use them to generate a normal map?

Regards,

Comment: I think you are looking for an addon like this one https://blendermarket.com/products/multibrush-multiple-layer-paint-tool. It is to work with BI but once the textures painted you certainly can use them with Cycles. I've not tested it.

Comment: @lemon If you suggested paid option I would recommend Quixel Suite. It's cheap and comes with great normal paint tool nDo. Also lots of textures and brushes.

Comment: @LukeD, sure! I did not wanted to incite to pay.

Answer (score 5):

### Final result:

[image: final]

### Overview:

As far as I know there is no way that Blender could generate normal map from diffuse map.

There is similar approach to what is going on in software like Substance or Quixel but it is painfully manual and not such fun.

In those apps you generally paint by stacking materials on layers and mask them one by one; and this you can do in Blender as well.

### Steps:

You will need both **Diffuse** and **Normal** texture for both materials and created texture for painting **Mask**.

***Node setup:***

[image: Node]

***Texture Paint:***

Set **Slot** to Image, choose your mask and start painting.

[image: paint]

### Final thoughts:

This is not ideal method especially when you need more layers/masks, this is why more and more people looks at software mentioned above (including myself).

There is another approach I can think of. You can paint your diffuse, then export it and generate Normal map in chosen app, then load it to Blender.

### Blend file (textures packed):

[image]

Comment: Nice, your nodes are worth a steal for my scrapbooks.  Thank you very much.