# What is the best approach to add rust spots in my Zamboni model for video games?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm overwhelmed with texturing at the moment.  Any time I look up a tutorial it deals with cycle rendering which I don't think applies to video game models.

I want to add rust spots or just grime in general to certain areas of my model.

[image]

Do I have to unwrap the model and directly paint the entire unwrapped area?  Should I add the rust as decals?  Can I have the rust generated in somehow with Blender?  SHould I make a normal map and have a generated rust texture appear via the normal filter?

I'm also confused as to which approach affects game performance.  Do generated textures offer better performance than small repeating seamless textures?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Painting on the texture would give the best result for realism and credibility, a program like substance painter works very well for this sort of thing, blender can do a similar operation but is much less powerful. Your model should be unwrapped in a way where it is organised and structured so you can pinpoint good rust spots and apply them with precision.Using direct painting over decals can result in a better variation on the material, hope that helps :)

Comment: Substance painter:  interesting.  So this program has rust brushes?  Is it open source?

Comment: Substance painter works by getting materials and painting them on with a whole multitude of brush styles, you can paint on the uv map or directly onto the model with whatever rust materials you can find, it cost $150 but has a free trial if you wanna check it out (no, no open source)

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76389/normal-map-when-painting-in-blender/76395#76395 it's an example with painting moss texture with normal map. Same way you would make it in Substance Painter - using masking layer.

Comment: The example you linked is using Cycles Render.  I'm looking for video game texturing not for animation.

Comment: You can use Cycles to create, then bake textures for the game. You should specify in your question which render engine are you using in Blender to create them. Also you didn't tell us which game engine are you are willing to use.

Comment: I haven't picked a game engine yet.  I decided to use cycles and bake the textures.  Best flexibility I think.  Trying it out.